# Blue spots after applying texture

Tags: texturing, uv, image, uv-image-editor

There are blue spots appeared when I applied my texture on the mesh. How can this possibly be fixed?
[image]

Comment: Check your normals, maybe it might be a normal issue?

Comment: can you add a picture of your material setup?

Comment: Try going to the overlays and have a look if face orientation is ON